# Scrollify - get last viewed section

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

Is there any way to get last viewed section index/id/class when moving to next or previous section using scrollify.js?

Am looking for any predefined function like scrollify.current() for getting last viewed section.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not able to find any predefined class, so wrote my own function.

```
var prevIndex = 0;

$.scrollify({
    before:function(index, sections) {
    var prevSection = '#'  + getScrollifySectionID(prevIndex)
    prevIndex = index;                  

    //Do your code with PrevSection(ID).

    }
});

function getScrollifySectionID(index){
    var sectionID = '';
    $('.scrollify-section').each(function(i){                               
        if(i == index){                     
            sectionID = $(this).data('section');                
        }
    });         
    return sectionID;
};
```