# Use `move` method for neighbouring section, and `instantMove` for non-neighbouring section

Tags: jquery-scrollify

Am looking for a way to animate the scrollbar only when moving between neighbouring sections. Scrollify gives you the `move` and `instantMove` methods which does that but I need help with the logic of working out whether the section am about to move to is a neighbouring or non-neighbouring section.

Is there way to pass in additional info into the `afterRender` method or a suggestions to achieve my goal?

```
afterRender: function() {

 $(".pagination a").on("click", function() {
  $.scrollify.move($(this).attr("href"));
 });
}
```

Comment: I found a stackoverflow answer that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45431016/scrollify-get-last-viewed-section

Comment: My issue is now that afterRender runs only index at the start, so does that mean I need to add my code to the `before`??? @RaJesh RiJo can you help with this?

Comment: I don't get what is your requirement yet!

Comment: Imagine I got 5 sections and am using pagination to navigate between them. Assuming am on section, let's say 2, and I click to go to 3, the scrollbar should Animate. However if I go from 2 to, let's say,  5, there should be no scrollbar animation. I hope that's clear now.

Comment: you mean that, for nearest sections need to animate and others should not! am i right?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant

Comment: Then check my answer. Hope it works as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find this example [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/9y0hcdco/7/) for reference.

Here am trying to navigate between sections based on condition, that is targeting section should be nearest to current section. If the targeting section is nearest then scrollify animation will be added by using `$.scrollify.move()` function, else `$.scrollify.instantMove()` function will be executed.

Hope it helps.